# “Plusieurs” vs. “beaucoup de”

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, adjectifs, adverbes

I would like to say "I receive many emails ." Is it preferable to use plusieurs or beaucoup de?

> Je reçois plusieurs mails.
>
> Je reçois beaucoup de mails.

If both are equally acceptable, then is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 4):

"Je reçois plusieurs mails" means "I receive multiple emails'. So this is not the same as "beaucoup de" which means "many".

In French I wouldn't use "mails" but "email" or "courriel".

Comment: C'est peut-être moins correct, mais c'est courant d'utiliser "mails" en français.

Answer (score 3):

• "Plusieurs" means "several, (a) few"
• "Beaucoup de" means "a lot of"

Answer (score 1):

En outre "Plusieurs" may be used in any registers
"beaucoup de" is more colloquial.